# Connecting Audio Jack to Arduino

Tags: serial, audio

So I started working on a project of mine that is mostly software based which I have no problems with, but it includes electronics too. Where I am still learning a lot. Anyways, I have been trying to figure out why I couldn't properly communicate over serial to a hardware device over serial with my Arduino. Basically, I am connecting my hardware device to the Arduino using an Audio Jack.

The hardware device is running on 3.3v and the Arduino at 5v, which is probably the issue. But

Here the current Wiring:

[[image: wiring setup]

Audio Cable:

- Rx = Green Wire
- Tx = White Wire
- GND = Blue Wire

I would really appreciate if someone helps me out with the following questions:

- Is ground connected to where it's supposed to be?
- Is the voltage a problem? If so, what kind of converter should I add?

Regards.

Comment: Define: "talk".

Comment: Communicating over Serial. I just want to be sure I am not missing something obvious and that the cable is not the issue.

Comment: What is the "hardware device" you are "talking" to with that cable?

Comment: you've connected Blue wire, which you nominated as GND to a socket on the arduino that is labelled GND - so, yes, that blue wire is connected to GND - of course, since your three wires seem to be connected to a lump of what looks like chewing gum, there's no way to know if the blue wire is connected to the right place

Comment: if voltage is an issue, you want to look for a *logic level converter*

Comment: @JaromandaX, lol,  possibly conductive chewing gum

Comment: It's blue tack, and yeah it is connected.

Comment: @JaromandaX Where would I place it? I was worried that GND would have an voltage issue.

Comment: erm, where would you place the logic level converter? at a guess, on the logic level connections

Comment: This is something completely new, I'll do my studies on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Upvoted for the interesting idea to use an audio jack for Rx/Tx.

Comment: Assuming your hardware device wasn't damaged by feeding a 5V signal into it. You need to lower the voltage of the Arduino's TX pin. I'd suggest using a voltage divider (this only requires two resistors). Also keep in mind that with serial communication, you need to connect the Arduino's TX pin the the devices RX pin (using the voltage divider). And the Arduino's RX pin to the devices TX .pin.